# How to increase file upload size for dropzonejs with vuejs3

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I have made a vue dropzone component using dropzonejs. The component works however I'm not able to configure the dropzone to upload files larger than 256mb which I believe is the default. For testing purposes I have put 1mb(reducing max file size).

I have also tried putting my config code inside mounted beforeMount, create etc.

### My Code

```
<template>
  <div class="dropzone-container">
    <form
      :action="uploadurl"
      class="dropzone drop-area"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      id="myDropzone"
      ref="myDropzone"
      :key="`dz-${dzkey}`"
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="path" :value="currentPath" />
    </form>
    <button class="finish-button" @click="finishUpload">Finish Upload</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import * as Dropzone from "dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js";
import FileHandling from "../fileHandling";
const Dropzone = require("dropzone/dist/dropzone.js");
Dropzone.autoDiscover = true;
export default {
  name: "DropZone",
  props: ["currentPath"],
  data() {
    return {
      uploadurl: FileHandling.SendForUpload(),
      dzkey: 0,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    finishUpload() {
      this.$refs.myDropzone.dropzone.removeAllFiles();
      this.$emit("finishedUpload");
    },
    dropconfig() {
      console.log(Dropzone);
      Dropzone.options[this.$refs.myDropzone] = {
        maxFilesize: 1,
      };
    },
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.dropconfig();
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. There is no `ready` hook. Perhaps you meant `mounted`:

   ```js
   export default {
     // ❌ ready hook does not exist
     //ready() {
     //  this.dropconfig();
     //},

     // ✅
     mounted() {
       this.dropconfig();
     }
   }
   ```
2. `Dropzone.options` is a map of element IDs (strings), not element instances (`HTMLElement`):

   ```js
   // ❌
   //Dropzone.options[this.$refs.myDropzone] = {/*...*/};

   // ✅ `myDropzone` is a string that matches element ID in template
   Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {/*...*/};
   ```

Fixing those issues should allow your [`maxFilesize`](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFilesize) config to take effect.

Comment: I got confused by the fact that you couldn't use select by id in vue, thats why I was using refs. Thank you this worked however I had to use ```Dropzone.Dropzone.options.myDropzone``` for some reason and not ```Dropzone.toptions.myDropzone```. Anyway I was able to make it work, thank you.